# How to pause a workflow

Tags: c#, workflow, flowchart

So I'm trying to learn Workflow 4.0 by making a calculator using a flowchart. Here's my model:

[image]

It works so far. Now I want to connect the last Assign to the Switch, so it gets backwards and does everything again on the next calculation rather than creating a new instance of the workflow and running it over and over again. The idea is long-living workflow flowchart.

Any idea how do I make it pause after the last Assign so it waits for the In arguments to get changed before going through the switch?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[`DelayActivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734721%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)* activity. Set the *[`Duration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.delay.duration.aspx)* property.

> The duration of the timer that the Delay activity creates. If the
>   duration is set to MaxValue, the delay is infinite.

Like;

```
new Delay()
{
   Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
}
```

Comment: Not good. I don't know how long it will take for the new operands to be selected